# Changing the version using "nvm use <version>" does not work

Tags: nvm

[image]

I had to run as administrator but it doesn't...
Why is there no change?

Comment: https://blog.rtl.nl/when-nvm-doesnt-switch-7dd4a5761d1a

Comment: This method didn't work for me..........